# Swap project tabs per project folder in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

I have several projects I work on concurrently, and have files open for each one.  However, having a separate window open for every project is undesirable (mainly because when I Cmd-Tab/Alt-Tab between windows there are 5 different Atom windows instead of 1 and I have to squint and try to identify which one is the project I want).

I know I can open project folders in a single window, but then the tabs for all open files are all open together, which presents an even bigger problem for finding what I want, especially if each project has 4-5 files open.

Is there a way to

- have a single Atom window
- display multiple projects
- display only the open tabs/files for one project at a time, swapping when I select a different project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a package that does essentially this: [project-plus](https://atom.io/packages/project-plus).

(Tabbing between projects could be improved, but it solves the pain points I mentioned.)

Comment: FWIW, I've since stopped using `project-plus` which I was having issues with, and instead use `color-tabs` + `color-tabs-regex` to easily identify what projects files belong to.